# Can `tmux` get the display the current tty in window names?

Tags: tmux, tty

For example, in `tmux`, I name a window 'test', but how can I add the tty of the current terminal (assuming that is `pts/15`) to the end of window name with the `tty` command. Then it becomes `test pts/15`. So it can dynamically show the current tty of the window.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every pane is a tty, of course, if a window contains only one pane, the tty of the pane is the tty of the window, there is a builtin variable in tmux called `pane_tty`, it is the tty value of the current pane, `current` here means when you focus on one pane, the value `pane_tty` you get from tmux is the value of output of `tty` command in the prompt line in that pane (I think it is the meaning of "dynamically" in your post).

You can use that value like this:

```
set -g window-status-format '#{pane_tty}'
```